# Generic type inference from parameter/object without function

Tags: typescript, types

I have a generic type:

```js
type Alpha<T> = {
  enabled: boolean;
  params: T;
};
```

I want to create a variable like so:

```js
const alpha: Alpha = {
  enabled: true,
  params: {
    title: "hello",
  },
};
```

But that won't work because `Alpha` expects a type as argument. However, my whole point here is that I would like it to be infered directly.

Of course I could use a function like that:

```js
const createA = <T>(params: T): Alpha<T> => {
  return {
    enabled: true,
    params,
  };
};

const beta = createA({ funny: "title" });
```

But I would like to avoid having to create a function to do that. Is that doable ?

Comment: Short answer. It's not doable. You would need to manually pass the generic parameter to `Alpha` if you don't want to use a function. Does that address your question?

Comment: Well, if that's true it does answer my question. That's sad tho

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNmAFgQwDwBUB8UC8UDeAUFFBAHbIBGcEAJgFxSUD2zNyZA3MVGMgE7IAtgGdG6bgF9uhAMbMyI4LwHCRuAj2ABLYDUYByRBDhxmBgDSFJUZOvmLgMh0tsIUjeEjShIzAGYqgqLYeEQk5FQ0DFDA-ACuEFYkfMEiVtKEQA). Should I write an answer?

Comment: No, that's really not ideal. Just say that it's not doable as of now, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR;**
No, it's not doable.

Currently, there is no ideal way other than a dummy *generic* function to infer the type correctly. The only valid option without a function would be to  manually pass the generic parameter to the type:

```
const alpha: Alpha<{title: string}> = {
  enabled: true,
  params: {
    title: "hello",
  },
};
```